# How to get rid of multiple return statements in methods

Tags: java

This is bank customer class, that contains multiple return statement. My question is how can I get rid of those multiple return statements and I want to have only one multiple returns at the end of each method.

```
public class BankCustomer {
    //define the attribute
    private String name;
    private int chequeAcctNum;
    private double chequeBal;
    private int savingAcctNum;
    private double savingBal;

    //define constractor   
    public BankCustomer(String n, int chqAcctNum, double chqBal
    , int savAcctNum, double savBal)
    {
        name = n;
        chequeAcctNum = chqAcctNum;
        chequeBal = chqBal;
        savingAcctNum = savAcctNum;
        savingBal = savBal;        
    }

    //define the methods
    // Call withdraw from chequing method
    public boolean withdrawChequing(double amount) {
          if(chequeBal >= amount) {
            chequeBal-=amount;
            return true;     
            } else {            
            return false;
            }       
    }
```

Comment: Assign the condition to a `boolean` variable, and return that.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, a method with multiple return statements is perfectly fine. If used correctly, it can make your code more readable. You don't need to change the method.

If you insist, here's how to reduce it to one return statement.

Create a boolean variable that stores the return value:

```
boolean retVal = false;
```

And then check the condition:

```
if(chequeBal >= amount) {
    chequeBal-=amount;
    retVal = true;    
}
```

Then return the `retVal`:

```
return retVal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public boolean withdrawChequing(double amount) {
    boolean bRetVal = false;
    if(chequeBal >= amount) {
        chequeBal-= amount;
        bRetVal = true;
    }
    return bRetVal;
}
```